# Need help on a such that line that spans multiple lines

Tags: equations, programming

[image: conditions for linear programming]

How do you type the such that vertical line that spans three lines/equations? Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! You question is a bit unclear to me, do you intend `\{`?

Comment: I can see nothing; please, upload the picture with the interface (click on the “image” button above the editing window). If the system warns you about not allowing inserting pictures, just remove the `!` in front of the inserted line, some of us will reinstate it.

Comment: Please explain the relationship between the question and the graphic you've uploaded.

Comment: The question is a linear programming question where you are supposed to find the region that satisfies all three conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Three other solutions, based on the `aligned` environment. The 3rd uses the `dlrcases`environment, an extension of the `drcases` environment from `mathtools` by @Gonzalo Medina:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}%
\usepackage{array, setspace}

\makeatletter
\newcases{dlrcases}{\quad}{%
  $\m@th\displaystyle{##}$\hfil}{$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$\hfil}{\lbrace}{\rbrace}
\newcases{lrcases}{\quad}{%
  $\m@th{##}$\hfil}{{##}\hfil}{\lbrace}{\rbrace}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
  \left\{\setstretch{0.7}\begin{array}{@{}c|c@{\,}}
  \begin{aligned}
    x & \geq 0 \\
    y & \geq 0 \\
    x & \leq 5
  \end{aligned}
  &\! \begin{aligned}
  x+y & \leq 7\\
  x+2y & \geq 4\\
  y &\leq x+5
  \end{aligned}
  \end{array}
  \right\}
\]

\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace, right=\empheqrbrace]{equation*}
\begin{array}{@{}c|c@{}}
  \begin{aligned}
    x & \geq 0 \\
    y & \geq 0 \\
    x & \leq 5
  \end{aligned}
  &\! \begin{aligned}
  x+y & \leq 7\\
  x+2y & \geq 4\\
  y &\leq x+5
  \end{aligned}
  \end{array}
\end{empheq}

\[ \begin{dlrcases}
      \begin{array}{@{\!}c|c@{}}
  \begin{aligned}
    x & \geq 0 \\
    y & \geq 0 \\
    x & \leq 5
  \end{aligned}
  &\! \begin{aligned}
  x+y & \leq 7\\
  x+2y & \geq 4\\
  y &\leq x+5
  \end{aligned}
  \end{array}
\end{dlrcases} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\[
\left\{\begin{array}{c|r@{\;}l}
x\geq 0 & x+y & \leq 7\\
y\geq 0 & x+2y & \geq 4\\
x\leq 5 & y &\leq x+5\\
\end{array}
\right\}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Probably a tabular preamble such as `r>{{}}l | r>{{}}l` is better (needs `&` before all `\geq` and `\leq` commands). It is so guaranteed that all relation symbols in the left part are aligned with each other.